# How to assert structural object equivalence in C# (with strict type equality)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

How can you elegantly assert the following kind of equivalence between two .NET objects (ideally using the Fluent Assertions library)?

Two objects are *structurally equivalent* if:

- both objects are of the same (run-time) type, and
- the public properties of both objects are (recursively) *structurally equivalent*.

---

Note that `subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectation)` does not work  since `BeEquivalentTo` does not check type equality. For example, if we have two classes `A` and `B` each with a single property `object X { get; set; }`, then the two objects

```
new A { X = new B { X = new A() }}
```

and

```
new B { X = new A { X = new B() }}
```

would be deemed equivalent by `BeEquivalentTo`, even though their types and the types of their properties and subproperties do not match, and hence are not structurally equivalent by the above definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, but I would have hoped there was a more elegant one.

Define a custom `IEquivalencyStep`:

```
    public class StrictTypeEquivalence : IEquivalencyStep
    {          
        public bool CanHandle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config)
        {
            return context.Subject != null && context.Expectation != null &&
                   context.Subject.GetType() != context.Expectation.GetType();
        }

        public bool Handle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator parent, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config)
        {
            throw new AssertionFailedException($"{context.SelectedMemberPath}: Expected type {context.Expectation.GetType()} but found {context.Subject.GetType()} instead.");
        }
    }
```

And then check equivalence like so:

```
subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectation, options => options.Using(new StrictTypeEquivalence()));
```

Answer (score -1):

`subject.Should().BeOfType(expectation.GetType).And.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectation);`

Comment: This does not check type equality of properties (and properties of properties etc.), which is required by the recursive definition of structural equivalence as stated in the question.